# how to access thirdparty website

Tags: php, curl, authentication

```
//$out = fopen($localfilename, 'wb'); 
$url ="some https site name";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "sar:pas"); 
echo curl_exec($ch); 
return $ch;
//curl_close($ch); 
//fclose($out);
```

i tried with code for automatic login to thirdparty website

$url="some url name";
in the username password i used curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "sar:pas");
i alread fetech the username password from database table 
but i am not using file & i commented the belowed two lines the code
$out = fopen($localfilename, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);

i have tried with the above code its not working in https site
help me in this senorio

by
saravanamuthu
saravanamuthu@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "sar:pas");
```

is not needed , and instead you need to simulate the form on the page you're trying to login ( right click->view source and see what input fileds the login form has , then send the required values using CURLOPT_POST , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , you allso need to return the transfer and see how it whent )

Answer (score 0):

dude, What is the error you are getting exactly ?

try this, it seems to explain your problem : 
http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/